# What makes the i-th element of the diagonal of the inverse of a positive definite zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Is is possible to get a zero on the diagonal of the inverse of a positive definite (PD) matrix?

My try:

We can say since $A$ is PD, $A^{-1}$ is PD and all diagonal elements of $A^{-1}$ should be greater than zero but I am looking for different proofs. Here is one possible proof:

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a PD matrix which can be written as $A=V\Lambda V^T$ where $V$ is an orthonormal matrix of eigenvectors and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix including eigenvalues. $A^{-1} = V\Lambda^{-1} V^T=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j^{-1} v_{\bullet j}v_{\bullet j}^T$ where $v_{\bullet j}$ is the j-th column of $V$. Hence i-th element on the diagonal of $A^{-1}$ is $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j^{-1} v_{i j}^2$ which cannot be zero.

Is it my proof correct?

Can you add more proofs to the one I have included?

Comment: You're missing some inverses. To begin with, we have $A^{-1} = V\Lambda^{-1}V^T$

Comment: @Ben Grossmann: I edited my proof. Does it sound correct?

Comment: Your formula for the $i$th diagonal element is incorrect, but the idea behind the proof is correct

Comment: @Ben Grossmann: I just revised it. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes now it’s completely correct